# Any set $A$ and $B$ with $B \subseteq A$ and $f:B \rightarrow A$ is 1-1 and onto, then $B = A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to show if the statement below is true or false.

Any set $A$ and $B$ with $B \subseteq A$ and $f:B \rightarrow A$ is 1-1 and onto, then $B = A$?

I believe it is true.  The reason is because if $f:B \rightarrow A$ is onto, then every element in $B$ is hit from some value in $A$.  If it is 1-1, then for every element hit in $B$, there is exactly one corresponding element in $A$.  Since all items in $B$ are hit from one exactly one element in $A$, $B = A$.

Did I work the logic properly?

Comment: What about $B=2 \mathbb N$, and $A= \mathbb N$?

Comment: No, you did not. To prove that $B = A$, you need to prove that every element of $B$ is an element of $A$, and vice-versa. You did not prove that. Consider $\{1, 2, 3\dots\} \subset \{0,1,2,3\dots\}$ and $f : B \to A$, $f(n) = n - 1$.

Comment: So @Najib Idrissi, are you basically saying that in your example, even though the function is bijective, there might be one element in the domain that is not mapped in the co domain?

Comment: Even if my logic is wrong, is my conclusion still right?  I guess thats the part that I get confused on.  Is the statement still true?

Comment: No, your conclusion is not right. My comment is a counterexample: $B \subset A$, and there is a bijection $f : B \to A$, but $B \neq A$.

Comment: I understand now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f: 2\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ given by $f(2n) = n$.

You might be interested in reading about [Dedekind-finite sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-finite_set), which are sets $A$ for which this result holds.

With a tiny bit of the Axiom of Choice (e.g. Countable Choice) we can prove that a set is Dedekind-finite if and only if it is in bijection with $n = \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$ for some natural number $n$.

Answer (score 0):

No, consider
\begin{align}
B&=2 \mathbb{N}=\{2n \;| \;n \in \mathbb{N} \} \\
A&=\mathbb{N}
\end{align}
with the function
\begin{align}
f: B \to A \\ 
n \mapsto \frac{n}{2}
\end{align}
which is clearly 1-1 and onto.

The result can be saved for finite sets, since a function $B \to A$ that is 1-1 and onto implies that $B$ and $A$ have the same amount of elements.

Comment: So in an effort to understand, are you essentially saying that in your example, even though the function is 1-1 and onto, there might be some elements in the domain that are not mapped in the co domain?